# Exponential Variables - $P(X < x | X < Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

Find the following probability: 
$$P(X < x | X < Y)$$,
where X and Y are independent exponential random variables with parameters $a,b$ respectively.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Would I need to use Bayes rule and then integrate the pdfs? I'm also unsure as to how the integrating will actually work.

After using Bayes rule, we get:
$$\frac{P(X < x, X < Y)}{P(X<Y)}$$
From general results, we know that $P(X<Y) = \frac{a}{a+b}$, so all that's left is to find the numerator. Any hints on how to do that?

Comment: Start with $P(X\lt x,X\lt Y)=P(X\lt min(x,Y))$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Not sure how that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small aside: you didn't use *Bayes' Rule* to start, you used *the definition of conditional probability*, which states that $\mathbb P(A \mid B) = \mathbb P (A \cap B) / \mathbb P(B)$.

Some hints:

- Remember that to find any probability involving two continuous random variables, your job is to integrate the joint density function over the region describing the desired event.
- The joint density function of two independent random variables is just the product of the individual density functions.
- The desired region in this case is the subset of the $ST$-plane (using $s, t$ instead of $x, y$ because we need to have $x$ in the answer): $\{(s, t): s > 0, t > 0, s < x, s < t\}$

I'd suggest drawing that region of the plane and setting up a double integral over it.

Comment: What I'm mainly confused about is converting P(X < x, X < Y) into a density function. Since these two are clearly not independent events?

Comment: The density function doesn't depend on the event; the density function is a feature of the *variables* and their relationship to one another. Your task is, in this order: (1) find a density function for the variables (irrespective of that event), then (2) integrate the density function on a region that adequately describes the event. The joint density here will be the easy part; it's the region (described in the third bullet point) where you account for the complexities of that event and what that implies geometrically.

Comment: In this case, the dependence of the events $\{X < x\}$ and $\{X < Y\}$ is realized in the fact that the region you'll draw will not have an easy rectangular shape.

Comment: Well the density function for a exponential variable is: $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. I'm guessing we'll have to split the region into two parts for the actual integration. One where Y < x and the other where Y > x.

Comment: So we need to write $$P(X < x, X < Y) = \int_0^x \int_s^\infty f_X(s) f_Y(t) dt ds$$?

Comment: Whoops -- I deleted my previous comment because it was wrong, but you've got the right setup.

Comment: Ahh thanks so much for sticking with me! Really appreciate you helping me set it up instead of just giving me the set up.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the approach. $$\begin{align}\mathrm P(X<x,X<Y)&=\mathrm P(X\lt\min(x,Y))\\[1ex]&=\int_0^\infty f_Y(y)\,\mathrm P(X\lt\min(x,y)\mid Y=y)~\mathrm dy\\[1ex]&=\int_x^\infty f_Y(y)\int_0^x f_X(u)\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dy+\int_0^x f_Y(y)\int_0^yf_X(u)\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dy\\[1ex]&=\frac{a}{a+b}(1-e^{-(a+b)x})\end{align}$$

Net result - answer for problem =$(1-e^{-(a+b)x}).$